# Slf4j: Symbol not found

Tags: java, ant, slf4j, ivy, bamboo

I am trying to build a sample spring MVC using Apache Ant & the dependencies are being managed by Apache Ivy.

I got this message when a bamboo ant build was happening:

```
15-Aug-2018 20:41:09        [javac] import org.slf4j.Logger;
15-Aug-2018 20:41:09        [javac]                 ^
15-Aug-2018 20:41:09        [javac]   symbol:   class Logger
15-Aug-2018 20:41:09        [javac]   location: package org.slf4j
15-Aug-2018 20:41:09        [javac] /home/adi/bamboo-home/xml-data/build-dir/CICD-PIL-JOB1/src/com/infoseption/controller/HelloController.java:4: error: cannot find symbol
15-Aug-2018 20:41:09        [javac] import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
15-Aug-2018 20:41:09        [javac]                 ^
15-Aug-2018 20:41:09        [javac]   symbol:   class LoggerFactory
15-Aug-2018 20:41:09        [javac]   location: package org.slf4j
15-Aug-2018 20:41:09        [javac] /home/adi/bamboo-home/xml-data/build-dir/CICD-PIL-JOB1/src/com/infoseption/controller/HelloController.java:15: error: cannot find symbol
15-Aug-2018 20:41:09        [javac]         private final static org.slf4j.Logger logger = org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(HelloController.class);
15-Aug-2018 20:41:09        [javac]                                       ^
15-Aug-2018 20:41:09        [javac]   symbol:   class Logger
15-Aug-2018 20:41:09        [javac]   location: package org.slf4j
15-Aug-2018 20:41:09        [javac] /home/adi/bamboo-home/xml-data/build-dir/CICD-PIL-JOB1/src/com/infoseption/controller/HelloController.java:15: error: cannot find symbol
15-Aug-2018 20:41:09        [javac]         private final static org.slf4j.Logger logger = org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(HelloController.class);
15-Aug-2018 20:41:09        [javac]                                                                 ^
15-Aug-2018 20:41:09        [javac]   symbol:   class LoggerFactory
15-Aug-2018 20:41:09        [javac]   location: package org.slf4j
15-Aug-2018 20:41:09        [javac] 4 errors
15-Aug-2018 20:41:09    
15-Aug-2018 20:41:09    BUILD FAILED
15-Aug-2018 20:41:09    /home/adi/bamboo-home/xml-data/build-dir/CICD-PIL-JOB1/build.xml:41: Compile failed; see the compiler error output for details.
```

To be frank, I could not find a proper answer in stackoverflow, google, and github issues.

Regards

Aditya

Comment: Not sure how much you Googled, but this was the first result I came up with: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25706216/what-does-a-cannot-find-symbol-compilation-error-mean

Comment: Which slf4j dependencies did you include?